# Format DateTime to MySql Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, date, datetime-format

I have an ASP.Net application. I am using MySql on the back end. And I have 3 questions.

I have a field called BeginDate in MySql and it is of DataType: Date. It is written to the DB in this format: **2012-06-17**.

When I write a select statment and pull the date into a formview textbox, the format changes to this: **06/17/2012 12:00:00 AM**

When I try do update the date I get an error saying the date in in the wrong format at row 1.

Fair enough.
I type in the same format that is stored in the DB: **2012-06-17**.

And the Update works.

Where I am confused is, if the format originates as: **2012-06-17** in the DB

1. Why does asp.net flip it around and format it as: **06/17/2012 12:00:00 AM**, without me explicitly telling it to. And why does it ***not*** flip back to the original DB format?
2. How can I tell Mysql to accept this format, 06/17/2012 and not get the error?
3. I need to truncate the time stamp that is showing up in the text box. I only want the date.

Added note. The date is being set by an Ajax control calendar picker, which does format it:
06/17/2012
without the Time stamp. Which is what I want.

**Edit
Here is my update command and parameters:

```
 Update discount set DiscountPromotionalID = @DiscountPromotionalID,
 isActive =@isActive, Title = @Title, BeginDate = @BeginDate, EndDate = @EndDate, 
 DiscountPercentage = @DiscountPercentage
  where DiscountPromotionalID = @DiscountPromotionalID;" 

    <UpdateParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="oDiscountPromotionalID" Type="Int32" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="oisActive" Type="Object" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="oTitle" Type="String" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="oBeginDate" Type="DateTime" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="EndDate" Type="DateTime" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="oDiscountPercentage" Type="Decimal" />
    </UpdateParameters>
```

Answer (score 3):

Date's don't have a "format"; they're just a value.  When ASP.NET displays a DateTime value and no [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) is specified, it uses the default format for the machine it's running on (the server in this case).  In your case the default format is `"MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss tt"`.  Since your MySQL field is a Date (no Time), including a time component causes an error.

Before sending back to MySQL, format the DateTime to strip off the time component.  Since you didn't elaborate how you're executing the update (SQL concatenation?  parameters)? I can't give a concrete example.

**UPDATE**

Try using the [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to extract the date portion of the DateTime values:

```
Update discount set 
    DiscountPromotionalID = @DiscountPromotionalID,
    isActive = @isActive, 
    Title = @Title, 
    BeginDate = DATE(@BeginDate),
    EndDate = DATE(@EndDate), 
//etc.
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to figure out. I edited my OP to show my update statement. I guess, I need to figure out how to do this in SQL as well as C#.

Answer (score 2):

1) Without seeing your code it hard to say.  I suspect that is caused by the fact that you are assigning the date value to a DateTime variable.

2) I wouldn't do this.  I would just use the ToString method to convert it to the format you need. (see below)

3)  If you are dealing with a DateTime then you can use the [ToString(string format)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method to format the date however you like.  You will have to check but I think the following will work for you: `myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`